# how to import dat file in R

Tags: r

I have a `dat.` file containing one really long line. I have the specific layout to read the data but I do not know how.

What I have done so far(based on searhes in other posts) is try to use readLines, `read.fwf`, and also I tried to copy that line into one vector which later to split according to the logic in the layout but with no success. All of the approaches seem to encounter a problem with the length of the line in question which composes the entire dat. file

Any suggestions are appreciated!

PS: I am a beginner in R

I think it will be good to add an example so here it comes:

If we have a text file containing a single line as follows:

```
1 a 5 2 b 6 3 c 7
```

and we have the layout, in this case we need three variables with length 1 - the first one numeric, the second - string and the third one - numeric again

the imported data frame should look like:

```
1 a 5

2 b 6

3 c 7

3 rows, 3 columns
```

Comment: Suggestion #1: post minimal code you've tried that hasn't worked; Suggestion #2: post the actual errors you're getting or a minimal output example indicating what's broken; Suggestion #3: post a small sample of said "really long" line (not the entire line, unless requested) and also the length of said line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read dat files you need to use the command `read.delim()`. See `?read.delim` for info on how to specify formatting.

EDIT:

Maybe after you read it as a single line you could do something like this:

```
# Creating sample data
data <- data.frame(x = c(1, 'a', 5, 2, 'b', 6, 3,'c', 7))
# Creating the columns
a <- as.numeric(data$x[seq(1,nrow(data), 3)])
b <- as.character(data$x[seq(2,nrow(data), 3)])
c <- as.numeric(data$x[seq(3, nrow(data), 3)])
# Putting it all together
data1 <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

This works even if you want to create a lot of rows but gets tedious if you have a lot of columns. Honestly I have never had only a single line in a file so I don't know how to specify that directly when reading it. Hope that still helps though :)

Comment: Hi

Thank you for the answer. I was just looking into read.delim. I am curious how to explicitly set the layout. 

please see the example I added in the original code